# Is there any morphia query to achieve $geoWithin and $centerSphere mongo Operations?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

The existing Morphia Query:

```
q.field("somefield").within(addressLatLng.getLat(), addressLatLng.getLng(), degrees);
```

which gives a Mongo query like

```
{ "geo" : 
 { "$within" : 
  { "$center" :
    [ [ 38.8987037 , -81.52672820000001] , 4.341534008683068E7]
}}}
```

But this makes our application slow on loadtest, it takes around 400ms to execute, whereas the Query with mongo operations `$geoWithin` and `$centerSphere` query execute much faster about 9ms.

This the Mongo Query:

```
{ geo: 
 {$geoWithin: 
  { $centerSphere: [ [ 42.0494171, -80.0423151 ], 0.00758341759353 ]
}} } ---
```

I need a morphia query for the above stated Mongo Query, I have searched in morphia's documentation but there is no such API for `$geoWithin` and `$center`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those following this one, this is the issue filed on this request:  https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/522

-- Update 9/11:

I just pushed a fix for this:  https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/522

-- Update 9/12

Version 0.104 with this fix has just been released:  https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/releases/tag/0.104

Comment: The Issue is created by Me only in the Name of "vijay", if you observe that issue keen you could see that the paragraph above is I pasted there with some modifications. Anyway thanks for your  rapid response !!!

Comment: I did indeed notice that.  Was just posting the link for everyone else.  ;)

Comment: Thanks for closing the issue :)